# Xamarin.iOS crash on 6.1 simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

i recently received my Macbook and wanted to start developing iOS apps with it.
I Created a default Master-Detail App using the Templates in Xamarin.Studio and everything worked.
Now today i wanted to actually do something in the app, but didn't change a single line of code, still the app doesn't show up anymore in the simulator as long as i want it to use the 6.1 sdk for ios. if i use any other (6.0 etc) it works fine.

I already tried clearing my Cache in /Users/MYNAME/Library/Xamarin/ but this didn't change anything.

What would you suggest me to do now? can i simply reinstall the 6.1 sdk?if so, how would i do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you updated Xamarin to the latest version?

Comment: Just updated it, now fully up to date, but it's still not working with 6.1
This crash also happens when i try to start the simulator only in xcode on version 6.1, so i guess that the sdk is some kind of bugged.

Comment: You could check if your Macbook is fully up to date. But it looks like the sdk is broken, maybe reinstall xamarin or Xcode (First link I found on Google, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3784638?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Reinstalled XCode now, updating the SDKs currently. The Macbook itself is fully up to date. Will write again later. Thanks already :)

Comment: Nope,didn't change anything, simulator still instantly crashes when using iOS 6.1, anything else works.

Comment: Please show the crash report too, that might give a hint as to why it's crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the environment hang when I was trying to debug in the simulator (just showing the spinning ball). I found out that it only occured if I had my phone connected to the computer. Perhaps not valid in your case, but it might be a lead in your problem solving.

I'm using the latest version of everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

From within Xamarin Studio (or MonoDevelop):

`Project` -> `Your.Application.Name Options`

`Build` -> `iOS Build` (`iPhone Build` in MonoDevelop)

`SDK version`: -> `6.1` (it's probably still on 6.0)

This fixed it for me.  Also, it wouldn't hurt to make sure the target build in `info.plist` is set to `6.1`.

Comment: That's the version the app is build for,aka the minimum sdk version, which i set to anything between 4.x and 6.1 but didn't change anything either

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem several times again and my previous answer doesn't solve it.  Ya know what does?  Rebooting the computer.  Works every time.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Delete this folder:

`/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1`

And if your Library folder is hidden:

`sudo chflags nohidden ~/Library/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the Application name, Identifier, Version # in the project setting. 
I had the same problem and got it solved that way.